# Scala: isInstanceOf followed by asInstanceOf

Tags: scala

In my team, I often see teammates writing

```
list.filter(_.isInstanceOf[T]).map(_.asInstanceOf[T])
```

but this seems a bit redundant to me.

*If we know that everything in the filtered list is an instance of `T` then why should we have to explicitly cast it as such?*

---

I know of one alternative, which is to use `match`.

eg:

```
list.match {
  case thing: T => Some(thing)
  case _ => None
}
```

but this has the drawback that we must then explicitly state the generic case.

---

So, given all the above, I have 2 questions:

1) Is there another (better?) way to do the same thing?

2) If not, which of the two options above should be preferred?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `collect`:

```
list collect {
  case el: T => el
}
```

Real types just work (barring type erasure, of course):

```
scala> List(10, "foo", true) collect { case el: Int => el } 
res5: List[Int] = List(10)
```

But, as @YuvalItzchakov has mentioned, if you want to match for an *abstract* type `T`, you must have an implicit `ClassTag[T]` in scope.

So a function implementing this may look as follows:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def filter[T: ClassTag](list: List[Any]): List[T] = list collect {
  case el: T => el
}
```

And using it:

```
scala> filter[Int](List(1, "foo", true))
res6: List[Int] = List(1)

scala> filter[String](List(1, "foo", true))
res7: List[String] = List(foo)
```

---

`collect` takes a `PartialFunction`, so you shouldn't provide the generic case.

But if needed, you can convert a function `A => Option[B]` to a `PartialFunction[A, B]` with `Function.unlift`. Here is an example of that,  also using `shapeless.Typeable` to work around type erasure:

```
import shapeless.Typeable
import shapeless.syntax.typeable._

def filter[T: Typeable](list: List[Any]): List[T] = 
  list collect Function.unlift(_.cast[T])
```

Using:

```
scala> filter[Option[Int]](List(Some(10), Some("foo"), true))
res9: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(10))
```

Answer (score 2):

> but this seems a bit redundant to me.

Perhaps programmers in your team are trying to shield that piece of code from someone mistakenly inserting a type other then `T`, assuming this is some sort of collection with type `Any`. Otherwise, the first mistake you make, you'll *blow up at run-time*, which is never fun.

> I know of one alternative, which is to use match.

Your sample code won't work because of type erasure. If you want to match on underlying types, you need to use `ClassTag` and `TypeTag` respectively for each case, and use `=:=` for type equality and `<:<` for subtyping relationships.

> Is there another (better?) way to do the same thing?

Yes, work *with the type system*, not against it. Use typed collections when you can. You haven't elaborated on *why* you need to use run-time checks and casts on types, so I'm assuming there is a reasonable explanation to that.

> If not, which of the two options above should be preferred?

That's a matter of taste, but using pattern matching on types can be more error-prone since one has to be aware of the fact that types are erased at run-time, and create a bit more boilerplate code for you to maintain.